# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'samples.txt'

Tags: python, error-handling, glob

I want to load multiple data files using glob . Here's my code for the same.

```
from glob import glob

#file_names = glob.iglob("R_*.*_samples.txt")
coeff = np.loadtxt("H2_coefficients.txt")

data_set = []

n_vis = 2
n_hin = 10

epochs = 1000 # number of training steps
num_samples = 1000 # number of samples to generate from the RBM to calculate the H2 energy


for file in glob("R_*.*_samples.txt"):
    r_data = []
    
    training_data = torch.from_numpy(np.loadtxt(file))
    r = float(file.split("_")[2])
    
    r_data.append(r)
    
    for i in range(len(coeff)):
        if coeff[i][0] == r:
            r_coeff = coeff[i,:]
```

I am trying to load multiple text files of similar names. They are .txt files and I am getting this error. Kindly help

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-eb4dd52a165b> in <module>
     17 
     18     training_data = torch.from_numpy(np.loadtxt(file))
---> 19     r = float(file.split("_")[2])
     20 
     21     r_data.append(r)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'samples.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a classical off by one error. You probably want float(file.split("_")[1]) to get the second element, since the index starts at 0.

Comment: Great, thank you. Remembering indices from now on !